# Application of Composition of Functions: Real world examples?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, applications, function-and-relation-composition

Do you know of a real world example where you'd combine two functions into a composite function?  I see this topic in Algebra 2 textbooks, but rarely see actual applications of it.  It's usually plug and chug where you take f(g(4) and run it through both functions.  This leads to the idea of creating a composite function f(g(x).  But it's somewhat academic, and it's not like you're saving time b/c you need to run 50 different numbers through both functions.

While on this topic, where is this topic used in later math?  In Precalculus, you can determine the domain of the composite function.  In Calc, composition is used to describe the ideas behind the Chain Rule.  In Calc, you break down a function into the 2 components to show it's continuous. (If the components are continuous, so is the composite function)  Any other main areas?

Thanks!

Comment: There are so many real-world examples of this it's hard to pick one.  Basically any time you are doing one computation and then doing another computation, that is composition of functions.

Comment: How about 1 example?

Comment: A function is just a process that turns one thing into another thing. Anytime you're describing something that chains processes together one after the other you're composing functions. You find a probability distribution and then want to find its average. Find a particle's position as a function of time, and then its distance from its start point. Almost any time you want to do multiple things to a function you're composing it with other functions.

Comment: Any examples yet?

Answer (score 4):

You use composite functions whenever you buy a sale (discounted) item.  When you are standing in the store trying to decide if you can afford the item, the first thing you calculate is the discount.  For example, I want to buy this 20 dollar shirt, and it is on sale at 15% off.  This means that the shirt is really 17 dollars.  Now, you must calculate what the shirt will cost after sales tax (let's say it is 8%).  Your total cost for the shirt after the discount and sales tax will be $18.36.  This process of computation can be expressed as a composite function.

If f(x) = The price of the shirt after the discount
and
   g(x) = The price after sales tax
then,

The function for the final cost of the shirt = g(f(x)).

Answer (score 2):

First example of Algorythms: You have a list, compose by a head (an element) and a tail (a list). A composition of functions could return the second element of the list, let's say, L:

$ Head(Tail(L)) $

This is a simple examen in my field of study, I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, this almost seems like a recursive or embedded function call in computer science.  But, yes, this is a good general example of this topic.  Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone think of other examples in computer science where you can demonstrate this idea of embedded function calls?

Answer (score 2):

Think of an industrial plant that produce bottles of beer; first there is the operation (or function) $f_1$ that puts the beer inside the bootle, followed by the opeartion $f_2$ that close the bottle with the cap.

> > Clearly, these two functions (operations) do not commute ...

Answer (score 2):

One common everyday life example is unit conversion.
If I know how many miles and hours I have been walking, but want to decide what my average speed is in feet per second, generally what ends up happening is I combine several functions to get my result.  I know the number of feet in a mile, thus if $x$ is in miles per unit time, I have a function $f(x)$ which converts it to feet per unit time.  I also have $g(x)$ which converts length per unit hours to length per unit seconds (since I know there are $60$ seconds in a minute).  I can use composition of functions to take my miles per hour speed and convert it to feet per second; if I am doing this computation often enough, it will be helpful for me to memorize the composed function $h(x) = g ( f(x))$.

Basically any time you are doing one computation, $f$, and then using that result to do another computation, $g$, that is composition of functions.  In particular, if you wanted to make this computation go faster in the future, you could memorize the function $g \circ f$.

Some more real-word examples can be found [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/fcncomp5.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the set of fruit in your preferred grocery store. There is a function $f:A\to \mathbb R^+$ that maps a fruit to its weight in kilogramss. There is also a function $g:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R^+$ which converts a kilogram weight to the same weight measured in tonnes.

Consider the function $g\circ f:A \to \mathbb R$. It is the function which measures the weight of the fruit of your grocer in tonnes.

Answer (score -1):

In electrical engineering, the application of the composition comes where you are having an electrical motor with it power(ex: 25 KVA) and you want to know the equivalent propeller (mechanical machine : XX power-horse)that can be used with the electrical motor. Then you need eventually to use the composition of the function F1 which is a fonction of the  electrical motor and the function F2 which is the unknown power-horse of the propeller.F2 (f1)=F2 o f1. In fact it is the composition of the function that the physician use to establish relationship between different physical quantity. Ex: conversion from horse-power to electrical power. 1horse-power =745.7 kilowatts.

Answer (score -2):

Many people believe that $+$ is a binary function. They are wrong. Since Haskell Curry it is known that $+$ is in fact an unary function, operating on numbers and returning another function, also operating on numbers. $a+b$ is a shorthand for a composition $(+(a))(b)$

Same goes for any other $n$-ary function, of course.